# How to format double value in a templatefield of a gridview

Tags: asp.net

In a web application I'm having a gridview with a templatefield. I have bind data to that templatefield by a calculation of two double values.
But when the page loads, the templatefield display a value with more than 15 decimal places. I want to format the templatefield into 2 decimal places. Any suggestions please??

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<%# Eval("DoubleField", "{0:0.00}") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can write in templated field while binding value to field. This will give you exact what you want.

```
Text='<%# Convert.ToDecimal( Eval("double")).ToString(#.##) %>'
```

Comment: I'm using the Text as this

Text='<%# ((Double)Eval("amount1"))-((Double)Eval("amount2")) %>'

I'm very new to asp.net. so I have no much idea about this